# UI-router state change, trigger youtube video play on next state

Tags: angularjs, video, youtube, angular-ui-router

I want to be able to click a play button on the home page, which will trigger a state change via ui-sref to the video page. After the state change has ended and on the video page, the single youtube video should start playing. The video should only play if the play button was clicked on the home page. The video should not play on video page reload.
Can anyone help? If not sure about the video play trigger, if you can provide info on how to trigger an event on the following state, that would help.
Here is the button markup:

```
    <button class="play-button" ui-sref="video"><i class="fa fa-play fa-play--sm"></i><span>PLAY</span></button>
```

Here is my app.js markup:

```
    var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", [ 'ui.router','ui.bootstrap' ]);
    MyApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
/*** ROUTING ***/
$stateProvider
.state("home", {
    url: "/",
    controller: "HomeCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/Templates/index.html"
})

.state("video", {
    url: "/video",
    controller: "VideoCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/Templates/video.html"
})
.state('otherwise', {
    url: '/'
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

}]);
```

I'm using a directive for the youtube video on the video page. If it helps to see the directive code, let me know.

```
    <youtube videoid="{{fullEpvidId}}"></youtube>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add the `params` object to your `video` state definition:

> A map which optionally configures parameters declared in the url, or defines additional non-url parameters.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#params

Add a the `params` object with a `play` property that defaults to `false`:

```
.state("video", {
    url: "/video",
    controller: "VideoCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/Templates/video.html",
    params: {
        play: false
    }
})
```

Then in your `ui-sref` directive add the `play` parameter to the state and set it to `true`:

```
<button class="play-button" ui-sref="video({play: true})"><i class="fa fa-play fa-play--sm"></i><span>PLAY</span></button>
```

Now in your `VideoCtrl` method you can access the `$stateParams` object for the `play` property. It will be set to true when the state is accessed via the above `ui-sref` otherwise it will default to false:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('VideoCtrl', [
             '$scope', '$stateParams',
    function ($scope,   $stateParams) {
        $scope.play = $stateParams.play;
    }
]);
```

Would have added a working example in a snippet but that's impossible in this particular case. Code is done freehanded and am unable to test it at the moment but in concept it should work. Good luck!